# How to set start Value on Event Receiver

Tags: event-receivers

I must set a Value in Items Adding, it should be start Value of element. How could I set a Value. Like Default Value But that will be number User1, User2, User3 To Unical identyfy User.

I have got code, how to set start value of elementco list "Jawna":

```
    /// </summary>
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
        base.ItemAdded(properties);
        if (properties.List.Title == "Jawna")
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList FirstItem = properties.Web.Lists["Jawna"];
                    SPList lstOtherList = properties.Web.Lists["Niejawna"];
                    SPListItem item = lstOtherList.Items.Add();
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    item["UnikalnaNazwa"] = "User" + Convert.ToInt32((FirstItem.ItemCount)+1);
                    item["Title"] = properties.AfterProperties["Title"].ToString();
                    item["B"] = properties.AfterProperties["B"].ToString();
                    item["Status"] = properties.AfterProperties["Status"].ToString();
                    item.Update();
                }
```

Comment: First of all, the code above is an `ItemAdded` event receiver, not an `ItemAdding` (or you have missed the point of naming your methods correctly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [link](http://srisharepointdevelopment.blogspot.de/2013/06/beforeproperties-and-afterproperties-in.html) always to be very useful, when it came to understand SharePoint EventReceiver. Looking a the link, you'll find out that it's better to use properties.ListItem["Title"] instead of Afterproperties, because that way you'll get a value for sure. But it should be working anyway (if a value is being added in the first item). Also you shouldn't forget to set "web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;" at the end.

From what I see you're trying to add a new item to List B for every item which gets added to List A. Besides some optimizations which jump to my eye, I don't see why your code shouldn't be working.

Could you please explain your problem in more detail and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I mast have a set start value when the popap show on the screen.

Comment: If you want to have a default value for a certain column/field when you open up the NewForm.aspx you have to use Javascript as there is no way to achieve this using the SharePoint Server Object Model. Have a look at this [link](http://spjsblog.com/2013/08/12/dynamic-forms-for-sharepoint-v3/) to see if this fits your needs.

Comment: But how. Could You give any Example of code please?

Comment: Could you please follow the [link](http://spjsblog.com/2010/05/28/get-or-set-value-for-sharepoint-field-in-newform-editform-and-dispform-get-only-in-dispform/) and read what's written there? It's part of the dynamic forms and contains all the required information to do what you want. I don't think it's necessary to paste the code here.